# Protractor unexpected console errors when running tests containing Selenium code

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

I am starting up an Angular 4 project, which I have done with `ng new [myProjectName]` and generating Components with `ng g c [componentName]`. Basically, I have let the Angular command-line framework handle the core necessities (such as generating spec ts files, adding components to `app.module.ts`) for me. I have previously installed and ran Selenium on my machine, months ago (I was being trained as SDET, during which I learned Angular, Selenium WebDriver, Protractor, and soooo much more).

When I say `ng test` inside the project's root folder, all is good. However, when I start putting Selenium code in my component's spec ts file, hell breaks loose.

I put some business code in my `banner.component.html`:

```
<nav>
    <button id="menuButton" (click)="toggleMenuVisible()">
        <div id="menuBars">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <a id="pageTitle" routerLink="/home">Open Source Roads</a>
</nav>
<!-- NOTE: <menu> here corresponds to MenuComponent, not the HTML5 menu tag -->
<menu *ngIf="menuVisible"></menu>
```

put some business logic in `banner.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.css']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  public menuVisible = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public toggleMenuVisible() { 
    this.menuVisible = !this.menuVisible;
  }

}
```

and then put some dummy Selenium code in the `banner.component.spec.ts` :

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BannerComponent } from './banner.component';
import { element, by } from 'protractor';

describe('BannerComponent', () => {
  let component: BannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BannerComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should toggle menu on/off when menu button is clicked', () => { 
    // reset component's menuVisible to false
    component.menuVisible = false;
    // click the menuButton
    expect(element(by.id('menuButton'))).toBeTruthy() // this is causing a slew of errors on the console. WHY.jpeg
  })
});
```

Running `ng test` after that produces screens worth of scary red text, followed by 2 unsuccessful attempts to start up Karma in my browser.

[image]

How do I fix this so that I can get back to test driven development?

Comment: Why are you using Protractor in a unit test. This does not look right.

Comment: Protractor tests should be executed using `ng e2e`, e2e tests are stored in separate folder.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you to use Cypress instead of protractor for E2E tests...

Comment: The ng test is used for unit tests. I'll try to suggest an answer in the next few hours how to fix your unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why you should not use Protractor with TestBed

When you run `ng test`, you are running TestBed style tests and not Protractor. These currently do not work together when you import Protractor into a unit style test.

Instead of calling `element(by.id(...)).click()` think about using the `nativeElement` that you can get from the fixture. After you call the click method, you can check variables set in the component. Next you will call `detectChanges` and can check the view.

### Code snippet

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BannerComponent } from './banner.component';

describe('BannerComponent', () => {
  let component: BannerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BannerComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BannerComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should toggle menu on/off when menu button is clicked', () => { 
    // reset component's menuVisible to false
    component.menuVisible = false;

    // click the menuButton
    let menuButton = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement
        .querySelector('[id="menuButton"]');
    menuButton.click();
    // after the click we could check to see if the component class
    // has variables changed because of the click.
    expect(component.menuVisible).toBeTruthy();

    fixture.detectChanges();
    // we could now detect changes in the view
  })
});
```

### Another example of testing with nativeElement

Here is an example of this at work:

- Check the component variables have changed before detect changes. See https://github.com/angular-seattle/protractor-new-hope/blob/master/src/app/tractor-control/tractor-control.component.spec.ts#L36
- Check the component view has changed after detect changes. See https://github.com/angular-seattle/protractor-new-hope/blob/master/src/app/tractor-control/tractor-control.component.spec.ts#L43

Alternatively, you could call `detectChanges` and run both checks for component variables and view.

Answer (score 0):

it happens if you have `"import 'jasmine'"` in one of your tests, try to remove it or add this to `karma.conf.js`:

```
webpack: { node: { tls: 'empty', } }
```

hope that helps.

**update:**

another solution is installing `json-loader` so that `webpack` can handle `*.json` files. Then add that loader and a new node object to your `webpack.config.js` like so:

```
$ npm install --save-dev json-loader
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: 'index',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js']
  },
  node: {
    console: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Comment: @MikeWarren do you get any new error or same errors?

Comment: Where does that `webpack.config.js` go?